# How to remove the display cable from Dell Inspiron 14-3473 motherboard

Tags: motherboard, dell-inspiron, dell

I am trying to change the motherboard of a Dell Inspiron 14-3473. I have removed all the connector cables except the display cable.

I don't know how to remove it and I don't want to force it. I am afraid of damaging it.

Can anyone show me how to remove it?

It's the part circled in red:
[image: It's the part circled in red]

[image: Here's another image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/Yy-MTVn91Zo?feature=shared&t=104

Comment: You can search the name of the motherboard (or the name of a laptop model that uses that motherboard) on youtube to find people disassembling it.

Comment: I actually saw that particular video in my search but if you look closely, you'll notice that the connector on the motherboard in that video is different from mine. I tried lifting it up like he did in that video but it didn't work.

Comment: the second picture is in focus at top edge, not where it should be in focus ... please review pictures before adding them to the question